# ecg rate using sliding window with neurokit2 in python

Tags: python, ekg

I am trying to calculate the ecg rate using a sliding window of 180 sec with a step of 15 sec. The respiration rate (rsp_rate) allows for the use of a sliding window but I have not found similar documentation for ecg_rate similar to rsp_rate. Does anyone know how to apply that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, NeuroKit does not directly support specifying a window size for the `ecg_rate` function, but you can modify the width of the Gaussian kernel that they convolve with the ECG signal here in this [function](https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit/blob/3d004b4777c3e59b288f46b9f0f812ac1e04b5d4/neurokit2/ecg/ecg_findpeaks.py#L206). From the function:

> SD is defined as a typical QRS size, which for adults if 100ms

I hope it helps.

Comment: that's too bad that direct sliding window is not supported. Thank you for your thoughtful response!